# Variables in JavaScript: An error arrives

Tags: javascript, html, variables

When I am starting my website, the JavaScript does not work. Safari gives an error:

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("aktuell").innerHTML')

This is my JavaScript-code:

```
<script>
var aktueller = document.getElementById("aktuell").innerHTML;
function go() {
    neu = aktueller - 1;
    document.getElementById("aktuell").innerHTML = neu;
    if (neu == 1) {
        document.getElementById("zweite").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("dritte").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (neu == 2) {
        document.getElementById("dritte").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (neu == 0) {
        document.getElementById("erste").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("zweite").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("dritte").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is my used body-part:

```
<body>
<p id="aktuell" style="display:none;" >0</p>
<center>
    <button>Zur&uuml;ck</button><button onclick="go();">Weiter</button>
</center>
<div id="nullte"><img src="data/nullte.jpg" width="500px" /></div>
<div id="erste"><img src="data/erste.jpg" width="500px" /></div>
<div id="zweite"><img src="data/zweite.jpg" width="500px" /></div>
<div id="dritte"><img src="data/dritte.jpg" width="500px" /></div>
</body>
```

Comment: If your script is in the `<head>`, the element you're looking for will not yet be part of the DOM - the browser runs the scripts immediately before proceeding to parse the rest of the HTML. You can move your script to the very end of the `<body>`.

Comment: The JavaScript executes before the DOM is loaded, so no element with that ID exists yet. Either move your script to the bottom if the page or do everything in `window.onload`.

Answer (score 3):

you have to wait until the page is completely loaded:

```
<script>
    var aktueller = null;
    window.onload = function(){
        aktueller = document.getElementById("aktuell").innerHTML;
    }
    function go() {
        //....
    }
</script>
```

you can also do it like:

```
var aktueller = null;
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    aktueller = document.getElementById("aktuell").innerHTML;
});
```

the other option is to use onload event on body tag:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var aktueller = null;
    function init(){
        aktueller = document.getElementById("aktuell").innerHTML;
    }
    function go(){
        //...
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
</body>
```

although if you use jquery you have other options like:

```
var aktueller = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    aktueller = $("#aktuell").html();
});
```

Comment: Why use jQuery to wait until the DOM is ready, but not to select the relevant elements?

Comment: I myself usually do my stuff with vanilla JavaScript, but I wanted to mention all the options.

Comment: Then why not `$("#aktuell").html();`?

Answer (score 0):

When the script is evaluated, the Body is not yet built. You need to place the script and the end of the body, or put it inside of a document ready section, by using jQuery.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var aktueller = document.getElementById("aktuell").innerHTML;
    /* more code goes here */ 
 });
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Why I would avoid using `window.onload` [here](http://perfectionkills.com/onloadfunction-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Uhm, no JQuery tag present and since this can be done with vanilla JavaScript (obviously, since jQuery is built in vanilla JavaScript) easily, I don't see a reason to include jQuery just for this.

Comment: I don't understand the -1. I offered a plain JavaScript solution (moving the script to the end of the body). Also, I offered a better alternative, by using jQuery. I think the -1 is not correct (the answer is related to the question and is useful).

Comment: Okay, I agree. I removed my -1.